# Index is not created in asp.net core using ELK stack and nLog

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, kibana, nlog, elk

Following is my nLog configuration file

```
<extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
        <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"/>
    </extensions>
    <targets async="true">
        <target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" name="ElasticSearch"
        flushTimeout="5000"/>
<target name="elastic" xsi:type="ElasticSearch" index="myservicename"
                uri="http://localhost:9200"
                requireAuth="true"
         username="elastic"
         password="dd+A0Y=mmE1RgmIDoeHh"
                layout ="API:MyServiceName|${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" >
        </target>

    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="elastic" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Following is my Program.cs file

```
using ikvm.runtime;
using NLog.Web;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddLogging();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
try
{
    logger.Debug("init main");
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    logger.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of exception");
    throw;
}
finally
{
    NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
}

static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                }).UseNLog();
```

After this when I ran the code and search in the local host:9200, I can not find the index.
So I used this curl command

> curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/myservicename"
> and the index is created but I can not find any logs there

Comment: you mean there are no data/documents inside the index?

Comment: @sudhagarramesh , Yes no data/documents inside the index